# Image Upload using android and Laravel

Tags: php, android, laravel, laravel-5, image-uploading

I am trying to image upload from android but i am getting error in json. In i am using the following code.

```
public function expense(Request $request)
{

    $files = $request->file('image');   // file is name of input field
    print_r($files);

    if (isset($files)) {

        echo "True";
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            echo "TEsting";
              $destinationPath = 'uploads/expense';

              $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
              $savedFileName = date('Ymdhis')."_".$filename; // give a unique name to file to be saved

              $file->move($destinationPath, $savedFileName);


        }
    } else {
        echo "False";
    }
}
```

I am getting this error(attaching the screenshot)

[image]

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I has similar problem and it was related with image size. 
Check your image size, it must be less then value of `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini

Answer (score -1):

Try this [way](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/).

It is a very good tutorial to upload a picture from android, and to receive it in php.

Comment: hey i am getting the error in laravel not in android